# Incorrect URL when executing mysql query (not following php's header location instructions)

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, header

**Importante note:** I have set Location to 'Location:google.com'; and it neither works. This should make it easyer to detect problem, de you know why could it not redirect to google?? The entire code has been added at the end of the post.

---

I've been stuck here for time, and got no idea of what's happening.

On a form, when I click on submit button, my browser redirects me to a inexisting directory (localhost/Gestion/school_main.php), forgetting about instructions given by **header(location:...)**

FORM mysql query:

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($consultaCampos)==0) {
    $nuevoRegistro = mysql_query("INSERT INTO school_main(sc_id,sc_name,sc_cif,sc_web,sc_headmstr,sc_studDirector,sc_dir1,sc_dir2,sc_dir3,sc_dir4,sc_postcode,sc_pobl,sc_city,sc_country,sc_tel1sec,sc_tel1,sc_tel2sec,sc_tel2,sc_fax,sc_mail1sec,sc_mail1,sc_mail2sec,sc_mail2,sc_mail3sec,sc_mail3,sc_img) VALUE ('','$nombre','$cif','$web','$director','$jefeEstudios','$direccion1','$direccion2','$direccion3','$direccion4','$codigopostal','$poblacion','$ciudad','$pais','$seccionTelefono1','$telefonol','$seccionTelefono2','$telefono2','$fax','$seccionEmail1','$email1','$seccionEmail2','$email2','$seccionEmail3','$email3','$rutaFinal')") or die("No se pudo introducir contenido en la base de datos");

    header('location:/Gestion/panel.php?directory=forms/school_main/school_main');
}

else{
    $idCentro=$registroBbdd['sc_id'];
    $actualizaRegistro = mysql_query("UPDATE school_main SET sc_name='$nombre',sc_cif='$cif',sc_web='$web',sc_headmstr='$director',sc_studDirector='$jefeEstudios',sc_dir1='$direccion1',sc_dir2='$direccion2',sc_dir3='$direccion3',sc_dir4='$direccion4',sc_postcode='$codigopostal',sc_pobl='$poblacion',sc_city='$ciudad',sc_country='$pais',sc_tel1sec='$seccionTelefono1',sc_tel1='$telefonol',sc_tel2sec='$seccionTelefono2',sc_tel2='$telefono2',sc_fax='$fax',sc_mail1sec='$seccionEmail1',sc_mail1='$email1',sc_mail2sec='$seccionEmail2',sc_mail2='$email2',sc_mail3sec='$seccionEmail3',sc_mail3='$email3',sc_img='$rutaFinal' WHERE sc_id='$idCentro'") or die("No se pudo actualizar el contenido de la base de datos");

    header('location:/Gestion/panel.php?directory=shortcuts');

}
```

And the piece of panel.php involved on this process:

```
    if(!$_GET)
{
        include('config/shortcuts.php');
}
else
{   
    $directorio = $_GET['directory'];


            include('config/'.$directorio.'.php');

}
```

As you see on the FORM, under any circunstance it must take me to localhost/Gestion/school_main.php, but even if there are rows on $consultaCampos as if not, it always takes me there, where no document exists under that name... it should take me to school_main.php or to shortcuts.php

what am I missing? Thank you for your patience and attention. Any aditional info/code just tell me.

Comment: did you try hard-clearing the cache?

Comment: Hi Scrooj, I have just done and it stills take me to localhost/Gestion/school_main.php

Comment: Don't forget to use `die()` statements immediately after your `header()` redirects. This may solve your problem too (depending on how the rest of your script has been done.) Also clean up your formatting... Put a space between `location:` and your URL path, capitalize `location:` to `Location:`... Precision is often paramount when it comes to programming

Comment: Also, have you sent any output to the browser **before** you've declared the `header()` redirect?

Comment: Thank you for your attention sjagr;
- There is no other output before header. 
- I've followed your clean formatting instructions (thank you), but none of these solves the problem.
- I've never used die() statement, I am learning now whats that.

Very useful, hope I find reason for this.

Comment: Afer adding "or die" as well as "or exit", no solution.. it stills redirets me there - header('Location: Gestion/panel.php?directory=shortcuts') or die("unable to open file update");

Comment: What URL are you expecting it to redirect to?

Comment: Importante note: I have set Location to 'Location:http://google.com' and it neither works. This should make it easyer to detect problem, de you know why could it not redirect to google??

Comment: Hi Ant, on the second case "localhost/Gestion/panel.php?directory=shortcuts", on the first "localhost/Gestion/panel.php?directory=forms/school_main/school_main"

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I have written a webpage that uses the header location. Maybe you can see if you did something incorrectly:

```
    <html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/css/mobile-login.css">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/css/mobile.css"> -->

<script>
function goBack()
{
window.history.back()
}
</script>

<title>Register | Mobile</title>
</head>
<body background="../images/mobile/login-bkg.jpg">
<center>
<a href="http://localhost/m/">
<img src="../static/images/logo.png">
</a>
</center>
<div id="login-panel" class="panel">
<div class="panel-container">

<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","twitter");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

        $email      = isset($_POST['email'])?( strtolower(trim($_POST['email'])) ):'';
    $fullname   = isset($_POST['name'])?(trim($_POST['name'])):'';
    $username   = isset($_POST['username'])?(trim($_POST['username'])):'';
    $password2  = isset($_POST['password2'])?(trim($_POST['password2'])):'';
    $password   = isset($_POST['password'])?(trim($_POST['password'])):'';
        $accept_terms   = isset($_POST['accept_terms'])&&$_POST['accept_terms']==1;

    // Check for duplicate entries
    $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT  * FROM users WHERE email='$email'");
    if($result) {
        echo 'That email was already used';
        echo '<strong> <button onclick="goBack()">Go back</button></strong><br>';
    }

    // handle the error of the passwords not matching
    if ($password != $password2){
    echo 'Passwords did not match. Go back and try again, <a href="http://localhost/mobile_register.php">return</a>';
}else{
$sql="INSERT INTO users (fullname, username, email, password)
VALUES
('".$fullname."','".$username."','".$email."',MD5('".$password."'))";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "You are now registered<br>";
echo "<a href='http://localhost/m/'>Login</a>";
}
mysqli_close($con);
header("Location:http://localhost/m/");
?>
</div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cant find my error with this, thank you anyway for your attention.

Comment: I will try something similar to your code and see if I can figure it out. @Biomehanika