# header('Location: http://google.com'); not working

Tags: php

I am now on *Gestion/config/forms/school_main/school_main.php*. When I submit the form contained here, header does not redirect me to http://google.com as I've set, it redirects me to *Gestion/school_main.php*, resulting on an error as that directory does not have that document.

What's the reason for header not to be working? Any help? I am on localhost, ant this worked perfectly till today that I made a code cleaning... Thank you.

Oh, I add: it neither inserts or updates any info on BBDD

You have the entire form code here: http://www.snipplr.com/view/73556/problem-header2/

HEADER CODE:

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($consultaCampos)==0) {
    $nuevoRegistro = mysql_query("INSERT INTO school_main(sc_id,sc_name,sc_cif,sc_web,sc_headmstr,sc_studDirector,sc_dir1,sc_dir2,sc_dir3,sc_dir4,sc_postcode,sc_pobl,sc_city,sc_country,sc_tel1sec,sc_tel1,sc_tel2sec,sc_tel2,sc_fax,sc_mail1sec,sc_mail1,sc_mail2sec,sc_mail2,sc_mail3sec,sc_mail3,sc_img) VALUE ('','$nombre','$cif','$web','$director','$jefeEstudios','$direccion1','$direccion2','$direccion3','$direccion4','$codigopostal','$poblacion','$ciudad','$pais','$seccionTelefono1','$telefonol','$seccionTelefono2','$telefono2','$fax','$seccionEmail1','$email1','$seccionEmail2','$email2','$seccionEmail3','$email3','$rutaFinal')") or exit("No se pudo introducir contenido en la base de datos");

        header('Location: http://google.com');
exit;
}

else{
    $idCentro=$registroBbdd['sc_id'];
    $actualizaRegistro = mysql_query("UPDATE school_main SET sc_name='$nombre',sc_cif='$cif',sc_web='$web',sc_headmstr='$director',sc_studDirector='$jefeEstudios',sc_dir1='$direccion1',sc_dir2='$direccion2',sc_dir3='$direccion3',sc_dir4='$direccion4',sc_postcode='$codigopostal',sc_pobl='$poblacion',sc_city='$ciudad',sc_country='$pais',sc_tel1sec='$seccionTelefono1',sc_tel1='$telefonol',sc_tel2sec='$seccionTelefono2',sc_tel2='$telefono2',sc_fax='$fax',sc_mail1sec='$seccionEmail1',sc_mail1='$email1',sc_mail2sec='$seccionEmail2',sc_mail2='$email2',sc_mail3sec='$seccionEmail3',sc_mail3='$email3',sc_img='$rutaFinal' WHERE sc_id='$idCentro'") or exit("No se pudo actualizar el contenido de la base de datos");


    header('Location: http://google.com');
exit;

}
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? I'm betting you have something printing to the page prior to the header function call. *Any* output to the page (even whitespace) will kill the redirect

Comment: dont link to the scipt, provide it here

Comment: Even if it is a loooooooong script... ;)

Comment: provide the smallest amount of code that illustrates the problem

Comment: Ok I'll bring it here as "code", but it makes strange things as splitting the script into diferent parts, etc... give me a minute.

Comment: I brought header code.

Comment: Hi Botsko, I'll do that and see if it solves.

Comment: header('location: http:gg.com')  you are giving space  after colon write it as   header('location:http:google.cpm');

Comment: A space there shouldn't be an issue. If anything, there shouldn't be a space between the `'` and `location`. Some make that mistake. @Vickey

Comment: Can you try `header('Location: http://www.google.com');`?

Comment: If `header('Location: http://google.com');` doesn't work, then try adding `www.` or `header("Location: http://google.com");` or using double quotes `header("Location: http://www.google.com/");` @Biomehanika

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21532279/incorrect-url-when-executing-mysql-query-not-following-phps-header-location-in

Comment: Hi MonkeyZeus, I've just tried and no solution neither... This Google header is the last of a hundred tries to make header work

Comment: Hi Fred, I have tried all human possibilities to type a url, as well internal or external and none of them workd: it always redirects to th same interal url

Comment: I suggest then that you try a test file with only `<?php header("Location: http://www.google.com/"); ?>` inside it, and see if that works on its own. @Biomehanika - if it doesn't then you may have a setting on your server that's preventing a redirection. That test will say right away if it works or if it doesn't. `.htaccess` may be something that's at play in there as well. Could be anything.

Comment: Hi Fed, AT LEAST a good notice. The document with that unique content worked, it redirected me to google. What could be happening...?

Comment: Not sure. Does one or both queries work? @Biomehanika

Comment: None of the querys on the docuemnt works: theys don't insert neither update anything on DB. What does work is the document with the unique content: <?php header("Location: http://www.google.com/"); ?>

Comment: That's the reason why then. If your queries don't work, then redirection won't happen. Fix both your queries, then it will work. @Biomehanika - you would need an `if` then `elseif` then an `else` for a 3rd header as a last exit option.

Comment: I also noticed that upon query failure, you're using `exit` in `or exit("No se pudo introducir contenido en la base de datos");` if it fails, then it will exit, and just stop there. @Biomehanika

Comment: Ok this is really a good hint. I'll take a deep look into querys and I'll look if it is somewhere explained the 3rd level exit, as by the time I do not know how to do that. Very grateful Fred :)

Comment: You're welcome. Once you fix your queries, your header(s) will work. Make sure that all columns exist and that they are properly set. I.e.: `VARCHAR`, `INT`, `DATETIME` etc. and that your `POST` variables match. If your form inputs are not `named` and do not match your `VALUES` then that will break your query. @Biomehanika - Double and triple check everything. Even if "one" value fails, it will make the rest of the query/queries fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
 ) VALUES (
```

instead of

```
) VALUE (
```

in your insert query

Try this,

```
 $nuevoRegistro = mysql_query("INSERT INTO school_main (...) VALUES (...)") or die("No se pudo introducir contenido en la base de datos".mysql_error());
```

Comment: totally right Krish, but this has not solved redirecting problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: You have error inyour query and exit from that line, so that doesn't redirect into that page!

Comment: Now the error is solved and I have typed right what you told me. Nothing has changed, error remains..

Comment: Add `@ob_start();` top of your page and try

Comment: Nothing. I have added both @ob_start(); and ob_start(); without the @ and no change has happened

Comment: Did you check trhe table, records are inserted successfully! what is the mysql_error throws?

Comment: I have set error but got no changes... I'll have to kech table carefully. I'll keep you informed, thank you

Comment: I have added "or die ("Query failed: " . mysql_error());" at the end of each query and got no error shown, only the object not found screen

Comment: what os you have using for this devlopment linux or windows?

Comment: windows, and the fact is that this form has worked perfectly till today, that I rebbuilted a bit y site in order to order code and modularyze, and saved no backup (lesson learned) and it has not worked again. tomorrow i'll ckeck ths with my teacher and I'll tell you what was happening if this gets solved, thank you vey much for your attention Krish

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem is that you do `ob_start()` in first line of your script but don't do `ob_end_flush()` **before** using `exit()`.

Comment: I have removed both exits and did not work, neither with a unique exit after ob_end_flush(). Thanks a lot Dador.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is how you are handling your variables.

If you have any variable missing you will get

```
Notice: Undefined index: sc_tel1sec in page.php on line 26
```

In order for the header to work, all variables must be defined. Even if one variable is undefined the header function will not work. Try turning on errors in php.ini to check it.

try `if ( !empty( $_POST['sc_var'] ) ) { $var = $_POST['sc_var']; }`

on all related variables.